# A pair of function call operators

Tags: c++, operators

I have a function object A with a pair of function call operators (line 4 and 5):

```
class A{
public:
    A(int x) : _x(x){}
    int  operator () () const { return _x; }  // line 4
    int & operator () () { return _x; }   // line 5
private:
    int _x; 
};
```

Similar pair of call operators is used [here](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/matrix-subscript-op.html). The question is: do I need line 4 at all? Does the operator defined at line 4 will ever by called? In the following case:

```
A a(7);
a() = 8;
cout << a() << endl;
```

always the operator from line 5 is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes line 4 will be used, example:

```
 A a(3);  
 const A b(2);
 a(); // from line 5
 b(); // from line 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int  operator () () const { return _x; }
```

will be called when your object is `const`.

Also return a reference out is not the best design, it breaks data hiding rule, `set/get` functions are better choices. And you will be confused when your line 4 is called or when line 5 is called.

I suggest rewrite to:

```
class A{
public:
    explict A(int x) : x_(x) {}
    //int  operator () () const { return x_; }  // leave operator() for functor.
    operator int() const { return x_; }         // use conversion function instead 
    void setX(int x) { x_ = x; }
private:
    int x_;   //suggest use trailing `_`
};
```

Comment: *"variable name starts with `_` may conflicts with standard library variables."*..... the name `_x` is fine. The Standard doesn't allow names like `__x` or `_X` i.e variables starting with double underscore OR variables starting with single underscore followed by capital letter.